# Unable to list tag bindings for a GCP resource

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm trying to list tag bindings for a compute instance using python client libraries `resourcemanager_v3.TagBindingsClient`
but it is asking for a location parameter, which is not there in the request parameters provided in the docs. I thought that It will take the location of the instance as the location parameter if I provide the full URL of the instance but it results in the same error. Here's my code

```
client = resourcemanager_v3.TagBindingsClient()
request = resourcemanager_v3.ListEffectiveTagsRequest(
    parent = "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/{projectId}/zones/{zone}/instances/{instanceId}"
)
page_result = client.list_effective_tags(request = request)

for response in page_result:
    print(response)
```

I checked REST API for list tag bindings but it doesn't have location argument as well. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no location parameter for `list_effective_tags`. This was an issue in terraform and they solved it but not on python client libraries

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).